# Error al Instalar dlib en Wine (no encuentra el path de cmake)

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, jenkins, cmake

Estoy intentando generar un distribuible desde Ubuntu con Jenkins usando su shell junto con wine64 para Windows, de código fuente hecho en Python.

Necesito instalar dlib, pero la consola me devuelve que no encuentra `cmake` ni la variable de entorno asociada a el. Instalo cmake en Wine sin problemas, pero no parece quedar el path para que pip al instalar dlib la vea. Trato de agregarla manualmente y no encuentro la forma (`set` no funciona).

> 2:31:43     error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path.
>
> 12:31:43     You can install cmake using the instructions at https://cmake.org/install/
>
> 12:31:43     You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.

Como nota a parte, el script que puse en el shell de Jenkins es:

```
wine64 "$winpython3" -m venv env
wine64 env/Scripts/pip install opencv-python imutils cmake 
wine64 env/Scripts/pip install cmake 
wine64 env/Scripts/pip install dlib==19.4
wine64 env/Scripts/pip install pyinstaller
wine64 env/Scripts/pyinstaller --onefile run_windows.spec
```

Donde **winpython3** es una variable global que creé en Jenkins que apunta a ***python.exe***

El motivo por el que repito "wine64" varias veces y pongo la ruta completa a pip es porque no he podido activar el perfil env (pareciera cerrarse al terminar la ejecución de una línea) y lo solucioné de esta forma.

---

Agrego lo que sucede si intento instalar CMake directamente en la carpeta System32:

> 15:11:15     running install
>
> 15:11:15     running build
>
> 15:11:15     Detected Python architecture: 64bit
>
> 15:11:15     Detected platform: win32
>
> 15:11:15     Configuring cmake ...
>
> 15:11:15     -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
>
> 15:11:15     CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
>
> 15:11:15       No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
>
> 15:11:15       contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
>
> 15:11:15       code such as
>
> 15:11:15         project(ProjectName)
>
> 15:11:15       near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
>
> 15:11:15       CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
>
> 15:11:15       line.
>
> 15:11:15     This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> 15:11:15     -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>
> 15:11:15     -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>
> 15:11:15     CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>
> 15:11:15       The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
>
> 15:11:15         cl
>
> 15:11:15       is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>
> 15:11:15       To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>
> 15:11:15       that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>
> 15:11:15       unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>
> 15:11:15       Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>
> 15:11:15       Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>
> 15:11:15       variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
>
> 15:11:15       the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
> 15:11:15     CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>
> 15:11:15       The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
>
> 15:11:15         cl
>
> 15:11:15       is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>
> 15:11:15       To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>
> 15:11:15       that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>
> 15:11:15       unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>
> 15:11:15       Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>
> 15:11:15       Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>
> 15:11:15       variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
>
> 15:11:15       to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
> 15:11:15     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> 15:11:15     See also "C:/users/jenkins/Temp/pip-install-co09_g2i/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>
> 15:11:15     See also "C:/users/jenkins/Temp/pip-install-co09_g2i/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
>
> 15:11:15     error: cmake configuration failed!

Comment: por lo que veo creas el virtualenv pero no lo activas, `venv/Script/activate`

Comment: El problema ahí es que Jenkins no parece mantenerlo activo de una línea a la otra. De todas formas probé desde Konsole manteniendo el perfil activo y ocurre lo mismo

Comment: No he podido agregar rutas al ``PATH`` en wine, encuentro que en windows hay que usar ``set`` pero en wine no funciona